# Insert a file in Microsoft Excel 2003

Tags: vba, csv, excel, excel-2003

I want to insert a .csv file in an excel 2003 worksheet. I know how to add a linked object but I want that the file should reside in the worksheet rather in any directory so that I am able to open it in another computer without copying or linking the source .csv file.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: do you mean through VBA method ?

Comment: i am not quite aware of vba code but i can try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself. In Excel 2003 go to Insert -> Object -> Create from file

Select the file and uncheck link to file. So even if you delete your source .csv file this object will store your file and you can open it by double clicking on the icon.

Comment: Please remember to mark your question as answered, even if you answered it yourself!